# URL rewrite to remove trailing folder name

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a server, and have several folders under the /var/www/ folder.
We have pointed our domain name to the IP of the server, and by default we expect to load one folder as the website (since its not possible to point a folder with DNS).

I have written .htaccess in such a way that when you enter the IP or the domain name, the request redirects to the website folder.

However, whenever we enter the IP or the domain name, the name of the folder is getting added to the URL.

Here is the present .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
    #DirectoryIndex folder/
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ /folder [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ folder/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder/([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

where the folder is the folder's website
so,

www.domain.com

becomes

www.domain.com/folder/

Is there a way to rewrite the URL to remove the folder name?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : Added .htaccess code

Comment: When you type www.domain.com, what your excepted result?

Comment: And show your rewrite rules so far

Comment: We can't help without looking at your present rules

Comment: @anubhava I just added in the present rules. Kindly take a look :)

Comment: @RahilWazir I have added in the present rules in the question now

Comment: @VinZ When I type www.domain.com, I expect the URL to show www.domain.com, but show contents from www.domain.com/folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this in `DocumentRoot/.htacess`:

```
DirectorySlash On
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

# redirect /folder/abc123 to /abc123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# skip rewrites for real files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !^(index\.)?$ - [L]

# route everything internally to /folder
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That comment won't help unless you provide details. What URL did you try? Where is .htaccess located? Is it inside `/folder/` or a level above it? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thanks for your answer. I have my .htaccess in the document root (/var/www/). I tried www.domain.com, and it loads a page which lists all the files and folders under documentroot. It is required that when I type www.domain.com, www.domain.com/folder should load, but the URL should show www.domain.com. When I type www.domain.com/folder2, www.domain.com/folder2 should show but the URL need not be rewritten

Comment: Can you kindly explain what is happening here? :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you made an external redirect instead of an internal rewrite. An external redirect is denoted by the `[R]` flag (with optional parameter) and causes Apache to send a 301 or 302 header back to the client with a different url that client should request. This causes the client to show the new url in the address bar.

What you want is an internal rewrite. When you request the url, the url is internally rewritten to the place where the resource is actually located. You do this by omitting the `[R]` flag, and not using a domain name in the rewritten part. It typically looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried adding in this code at the end of htaccess, but it still does not rewritethe URL to hide the folder name

Comment: What url did you try, and what was the observer behaviour. What was the expected behaviour?

Comment: I appended your code at the end of my htaccess file. THe observed behaviour was the present behaviour, being www.domain.com loads contents from www.domain.com/folder but the URL shows www.domain.com/folder.



The expectation is for the  the URL to show www.domain.com, but show contents from www.domain.com/folder. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Remove the rest from the rules, then clear your cache and try again. This rule should not cause that behaviour. If you still see this behaviour, are you using a framework that could cause this redirect instead? I can't really investigate it right now, as I need to go somewhere right now.

Comment: I did the same, but the request adds a "/folder" to whatever request that is made. 
For example, if I make a www.domain.com/website1, the URL loads up one www.domain.com/folder/website1 and since that URL doesnt exist, there is an error thrown.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what you requested. It shows 'www.domain.com/website1` in the url bar and in the server it loads `www.domain.com/folder/website1` instead. This rule does not cause a redirect. This rule on it's own **can't** cause an external redirect to occur.